# Magento Data Migration using script

Tags: magento-1.7, magento2.2, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

I am trying to migrate data from Magento 1.7 to Magento 2.2. We have several custom tables and we tried by using some of the tools available in the market, which are free.

However, The team came to the conclusion that we will write some script to migrate data instead of using a plugin/extention. (because we found that some of the attributes or data is not migrating properly, and we dont want to reply on such things blindly.)

What will be steps to migrate data using a custom written script? What things should we consider before writting the script? Please share your views.

Comment: hi @Preetam, could you find any custom script for migration? Instead of using data migration tool

Answer (score 0):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-settings.html

this will help you out in data migration from M1 to M2, 
there were some steps which were required in this task.

**Before Migration**
Take backup of db of M1 and M2
Use copy of db from m1 instance
Remove redundant data from M1

**During Migration**
Do not make any changes in admin except order management (shipping, creating invoice, credit memos, etc.)

**Run Data Migration Tool**
From magento root directory in M2

Also I will prefer to have a backup of root where Magento 2 was installed. If you are planning to move from M1 to M2 straightly after migration, then I prefer you to have a copy of M1 DB, put it in your M2 root configure your config.xml file of data migration tool with this copy of M1 DB and run your migration.

commands:

for data migration:
php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.1.7/config.xm

for delta migration:
php bin/magento migrate:delta vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.1.7/config.xml

After migration(from root directory of magento)
php magento indexer:reindex
php magento cache:flush

Comment: Hello John, I am doing the same procedures you mentioned above, i am getting several errors. I guess it is because we have so many custom tables which are not able to migrate using this tool. Is there any way to migrate only core tables? We have huge amount of code in magento 1.7 which we are going to migrate in 2.2. It is helpful if we get atleast core tables'

Comment: Yes, you can use first migrate settings only step from M1 to M2 and about your custom tables if you don't want them in M2, then put them in map.xml file as ignore, by this way you can ignore tables which are not required during migration.

Comment: @John, The question is from custom script, not from using migration tool.

Comment: any one have custom scripts for migration ?

Comment: @jafarpinjar I'm also trying to migrate using script but not sure where to start. can you please point me out some documents or articles which I can refer?