# Migration error Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration

[![enter image description here][1]][1][![enter image description here][2]][2]I am trying to migrate data from **magento 1** to **magento 2**. **Magento 1** is on abc.com and **magento 2** is on xyz.com domains. I am getting this error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in
>   /var/www/siteurl/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 392

After running this command :

```
sudo php /var/www/siteurl/bin/magento migrate:settings -r /var/www/siteurl/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.7/
```

Please help me what I am missing.

Comment: look into this, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202854/magento-data-migration-using-script/202861#202861

Comment: look into this for migration : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240255/magento1-to-magento2-data-migration/240276#240276

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out 


Getting this error

Answer (score 1):

when you are run command to migration magento 1.9.3.7 to magento 2 at time..

**You need to supply full filename path to XML file not just directory**

also you can check  [Reference](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-migration)

Comment: Thanks but now getting this error

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

Comment: you can check here answer for your error
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47254965/10748606

Comment: please check my screenshot added to question. Is it right.

Comment: yes you can try now

Comment: I am not using laravel it is magento site. Please check the settings in the photo attached in question.

Comment: both sites are not on same host

Comment: currently which error facing now? share me screenshot

Comment: Screenshot is added to question please check